# Um EnumMap imutável é thread safe?

Tags: java, enums, thread-safety, imutabilidade

Um mapa imutável construído em cima de um `EnumMap` poderia ser utilizado em ambiente multi-thread ou há algum risco de problemas de concorrência?

```java
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, VALUE4;
}

private final Map<MyEnum, BObject> myMap;

public MyClassConstructor() {
    EnumMap<MyEnum , BO> mMap = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);
    mMap.put(MyEnum.VALUE1, new ImmutableBO1()); // imutavel
    mMap.put(MyEnum.VALUE2, new ImmutableBO2());
    // etc 
    myMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(mMap);
    mMap = null; // ilustrativo, todas referencias a mMap são descartadas 
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## O que é um objeto *Thread-Safe*?

É um objeto que, em dado contexto de uso, garante o acesso seguro a dados compartilhados por várias *threads* sem efeitos colaterais indesejados.

Esses efeitos colaterais geralmente ocorrem quando uma ou mais *threads* tentam modificar o mesmo conjunto de dados ao mesmo tempo.

Vamos supor que temos um objeto com um contador compartilhado entre diversas *threads*:

```java
int atual = 0;
public int incrementa() {
    atual++;
    return atual;
}
```

Suponha agora que duas *threads* T1 e T2 chamam, ao mesmo tempo o método `incrementa()` e ocorre a seguinte sequência de execução:

1. Processo T1 executa a linha `atual++` (total == 1)
2. Processo T2 executa a linha `atual++` (total == 2)
3. Processo T2 retorna o valor de `total`, ou seja, 2
4. Processo T1 retorna o valor de `total`, ou seja, 2

Obviamente isso irá causar um efeito colateral indesejado.

Uma solução é sincronizar o método ou o bloco que manipula o dado compartilhado, por exemplo:

```java
int atual = 0;
public synchronized int incrementa() {
    atual++;
    return atual;
}
```

Neste segundo exemplo, as duas *threads* não iriam executar o método `incrementa()` ao mesmo tempo no mesmo objeto. Somente uma de cada vez adentraria o bloco com incremento, portanto isso evitaria o efeito colateral.

É importante notar que a sincronização no método é equivalente a um bloco `synchronized(this)`, o que significa que o bloqueio é feito no objeto e, se houver outros métodos sincronizados, pode haver um gargalo. Um forma mais adequada para sincronização seria:

```java
Integer atual = 0;
public Integer incrementa() {
    synchronized (atual) {
        atual++;
        return atual;
    }
}
```

Neste simples exemplo, o código acima não traz muitas vantagens. Mas a boa prática de limitar ao máximo o escopo da sincronização faz com que haja menos bloqueis desnecessários, o que faz muita diferença em cenários um pouco mais complexos.

**Observação**: o exemplo acima é apenas para fins didáticos. É preciso tomar cuidado ao sincronizar uma instância de `Integer` pois em algumas situações o Java usa um *cache* de inteiros de -127 a +127. Note que isso não ocorreria se usássemos `new Integer(n)`, mas apenas métodos como `valueOf()` ou `getInteger()`. Uma prática comumente utilizada, inclusive nas bibliotecas padrão do Java, é criar uma instância de Object e atribuir a algum atributo da classe, então pode-se usar esse objeto como um semáforo exclusivo.

## E se não houver modificações?

Objetos não modificáveis são, por natureza, seguros para uso em múltiplas *threads*, pois não há risco de efeitos colaterais. Veja o que diz a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object):

> Immutable objects are often useful because they are inherently thread-safe.

Tradução:

> Objetos imutáveis geralmente são úteis porque eles são inerentemente *thread-safe*

Enfim, objetos imutáveis não precisam ser sincronizados para serem seguramente usados em *multithreading*.

## Um EnumMap comum é *Thread-safe*?

**Não**. Veja o que diz a docuentação (*javadoc*):

> If multiple threads access an enum map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map, it should be synchronized externally.

Tradução:

> Se múltiplas *threads* acessarem um enum map concorrentemente, e pelo menos uma delas modificar o mapa, ele deve ser sincronizado externamente.

## Um EnumMap não modificável é *Thread-safe*?

**Sim.** A resposta acaba sendo óbvia após entendermos os conceitos apresentados acima.

## Então nunca haverá problemas com objetos imutáveis?

**Depende**. Como disse no início, depende do contexto de uso.

Apenas para citar um exemplo, suponha que um mapa imutável contenha elementos do tipo ArrayList mutáveis. Se *threads* diferentes acessarem e modificarem essas listas, efeitos colaterais provavelmente irão ocorrer.

Além disso é preciso tomar cuidado com classes do Java que são inerentemente *thread-unsafe*, como a classe `SimpleDateFormat`. Esta classe estende a classe `DateFormat`, a qual possui um atributo do tipo `Calendar`, que é mutável. Aliás, ter atributos do tipo `Calendar` pode ser um problema em cenários *multi-threading*, já que ele é mutável.

Em resumo, deve-se analisar todos os objetos compartilhados por *threads*, incluindo seu conteúdo.

## E se eu precisar de um mapa *Thread-Safe*? Devo criar um *wrapper* com vários blocos `synchronized`?

O Java fornece mapas sincronizados para vários gostos. Vejamos alguns:

- [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): uma versão "nova" de mapa sincronizado em relação ao `HashTable`, suportando manipulação por várias *threads*, mas sem bloquear as operações de leitura.
- `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)`: retorna um *wrapper* sincronizado sobre o mapa, porém mesmo métodos de leitura são sincronizados, resultando em mais gargalos com relação ao `ConcurrentHashMap`.

## Referências de classes e *wrappers* sincronizados e imutáveis

A lista de *wrappers* sincronizados é:

```java
public static <T> Collection<T> synchronizedCollection(Collection<T> c);
public static <T> Set<T> synchronizedSet(Set<T> s);
public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list);
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> synchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m);
public static <T> SortedSet<T> synchronizedSortedSet(SortedSet<T> s);
public static <K,V> SortedMap<K,V> synchronizedSortedMap(SortedMap<K,V> m);
```

A lista de *wrappers* imutáveis é:

```java
public static <T> Collection<T> unmodifiableCollection(Collection<? extends T> c);
public static <T> Set<T> unmodifiableSet(Set<? extends T> s);
public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list);
public static <K,V> Map<K, V> unmodifiableMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m);
public static <T> SortedSet<T> unmodifiableSortedSet(SortedSet<? extends T> s);
public static <K,V> SortedMap<K, V> unmodifiableSortedMap(SortedMap<K, ? extends V> m);
```

A referência oficial dos métodos que retornam *wrappers* imutáveis e sincronizados está [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html).

As versões sincronizadas de classes de coleções são encontradas no pacote `java.util.concurrent`. Eis alguns substitutos para as classes convencionais:

- `HashMap` > [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)
- `TreeMap` > [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)
- `TreeSet` > [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html)
- `LinkedHashSet` > [`CopyOnWriteArraySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html)
- `ArrayList` > [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Comment: Oi Luiz, apenas para complementar a resposta, fiz essa pergunta pois algumas classes modificam seu estado interno em chamadas de método aparentemente inocentes. Nesse caso problemas de concorrência podem ocorrer mesmo que não existam modificações de estados evidentes para o chamador. É esse o caso, por exemplo, do `SimpleDateFormat` (veja http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/114/como-usar-o-simpledateformat-em-ambientes-concorrentes). Abri o código fonte do `EnumMap` e não vi nada aparente nas chamadas ao método `get`, mas, em todo caso, resolvi checar hehehe.

Comment: Faltou falar que o `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)` pode ser uma solução quando há modificações concorrentes.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Bem lembrado, adicionei uma explicação referente ao ´SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @Victor Embora a pergunta seja sobre um EnumMap imutável, realmente é importante apontar para alternativas. Adicionei uma seção sobre classes sincronizadas e imutáveis que podem ser usadas.

Comment: Note que sincronizar num `Integer` pode não ser uma boa prática -- os `Integer`s "pequenos" oriundos de constantes em geral ficam em Cache na JVM (em outras palavras, o objeto referenciado pelo field `atual`, após a construção da classe em que ele vive, é um "singleton", será compartilhado por todas as instâncias da sua classe). Dessa forma, se você tiver múltiplas instâncias dessa classe e diferentes threads operando nessas diferentes instâncias, você poderá ter problemas sérios de performance devido a thread contention!

Comment: @BrunoReis Você tem razão, em grande parte. O Java faz cache de inteiros numa faixa de valores e em situações específicas. Acrescentei uma observação na resposta explicando os pormenores.